# Flutter how to pass two arguments in route, parameters that have different classes?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is object that needs to pass as argument in navigation.

```
Test test = Test(name:'name');
SecondTest testSecond = SecondTest(id:'dfdad');

//This is not working
//Navigator.pushNamed(context, "some-screen",arguments:{test , testSecond });

class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final Test test;
  SecondTest testSecond;

  SomeScreen(this.test, this.testSecond);
```

}

This is argument for that screen. How to send multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create `Map` and pass the Map like below:

```
Map args = {
  'test': test,
  'testSecond': testSecond,
};

Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'some-screen',arguments: args );
```

after handle navigation like this

```
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SomeScreen(data: args));
```

you can retrieve data in SomeScreen like this

```
class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final Map data;

  SomeScreen({this.data});

  //....

}


class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {

  Test _test;
  SecondTest _testSecond;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _test = widget.data['test'];
    _testSecond = widget.data['testSecond'];

    //...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map values must be mapped to keys:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "some-screen", arguments: { 'testClass': test, 'testSecondClass': testSecond });
```